# Layout of phpmyadmin becomes messy in ubuntu nginx server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

The layout of phpmyadmin in xampp is fine. But why it is messy in ubuntu with nginx server.

**The sidebar**

[image]

**The menubar (menu are shown double)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're seeing the alt text for images that aren't displaying, please check your webserver error log to see if there's some reason the icons aren't being displayed. It looks like none of the icons are showing at all, which suggests a webserver misconfiguration or some intermediary security problem.

Is the phpMyAdmin folder in your standard web root or have you created additional nginx directives to share it out of another location?